# Watch Guard Total Security working over VPN

Tags: vpn, anti-virus, spam-filter, watchguard

We have a warehouse and 4 other showroom locations. All the 4 locations are connect to the warehouse through a VPN. If we get a watch guard for each location and connect through a VPN. Would it be necessary to get the total security at all locations or could it be configure to monitor each location over VPN at the Warehouse? Making it so we only need 1 Total Security instead of 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you would need the license for each firewall.